# How to add a front end to Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I was following [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) tutorial to make a simple `MVC Spring` project that accesses data with `JPA`.

Now I would like to add a front end, probably as a `JSP` page.

Before I just made a `Dynamic Web App` that contained web folder and I just defined servlet-url mapping in the `web.xml`. See pic below:

[image]

However now, the project structure is different and I can't find any good reference to how to include Web Content in the Spring project.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That tutorial uses `Spring Boot` to kickstart Spring MVC project. You are doing it manually. Therefore, you will need view resolver bean definition. Put your `JSP's` in WEB-INF folder and add this bean definition:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Or if you are doing it via annotations:

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver (){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
}
```

Also, probably worth of mentioning, if you are actually using `Spring Boot` to kickstart `Spring MVC` project and if you want to use like `Thymeleaf` template engine, then you don't even have to create view resolver bean definition. `Spring Boot` will scan your classpath and create default internal view resolver for `Thymeleaf`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for an answer. I would like to ask you 2 more small questions to clarify things. Where do you want me to put WEB-INF folder? I mean does it have to have any specific location? And then, is `InternalResourceViewResolver` used only in Spring, right? Is it typical?

Comment: `src/main/webapp` - take a look at @Wouter's answer. Yes. `InternalResourceViewResolver` is part of Spring.

Comment: Alright, done that. Would you mind giving any reference to the `InternalResourceViewResolver` so I could actually know why it needs to be there? Thanks a lot.

Comment: And what happens when you specify view name in `Spring MVC`? If you have a `index.jsp` page you usually specify `index`. Prefix is "/WEB-INF/" and suffix is ."jsp". And file is in "/WEB-INF/index.jsp". `InternalResourceViewResolver` will simply point which `JSP` file to use as a view for specific mapping.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you now are using a maven project. Web files are in src/main/webapp by default with maven projects.

So put the WEB-INF, jsp files etc in there, and normally you are good to go.

See also https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Should I then use servlets to communicate with front end?